# Are full copies of game manuals offered for download legal?

Tags: discussion, legal

In [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/24312/manual-for-age-of-wonders/102557#102557) a user states they own the original copy of a game and is requesting a place to find the game manual.

In one of comments of the first answer one user states

> As far as I know (though I might be wrong), it's illegal to reproduce
>   the full manual in .pdf without the express consent of the producer,
>   as it's part of the IP.

I've provided a second answer with the link a link to a PDF version of the complete manual, and I'm wondering if this is actually ok or if it would be better if I remove the answer.

Comment: For some games, you can even download them for free from Steam. Example: http://cdn2.steampowered.com/Manuals/231430/COH2_PC_MNL_web.pdf?t=1377281778

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not our job to police this, "thanks" to the Digital Millennium Copyright Act. Let the lawyers sort it out.

Comment: Agree.  If something isn't immediately apparent as being illegal, let copyright holders do their thing by filing DMCA take-down notices.  The linked site will deal with it as they see fit, and Stack Exchange will do the same.

Comment: That said, these types of questions encourage link-only answers.  Legalities aside, these are not good questions.

Comment: @fbueckert the link _is_ the answer. If the link goes offline, the entirety of the answer becomes incorrect. It's a different issue than if the answer remains correct but is hidden behind a broken link.

Comment: Arguably, the manual itself is the answer, which would still be valid even when the particular transcription isn't available anymore ... But I agree that we shouldn't block out questions just because the answers are links by necessity.